# Removing repetitive lists in a list of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists and i want to remove repetitive items in the list.

```
my_list=
[[[2, 5, 71.1], [1, 3, 70.0]],
[[2, 5, 71.1], [1, 3, 70.0]],
[[2, 5, 71.1], [1, 3, 70.0]],
[[5, 10, 80.0], [6, 9, 80.0], [5, 8, 80.0]],
[[5, 10, 80.0], [6, 9, 80.0], [5, 8, 80.0]],
[[5, 10, 80.0], [6, 9, 80.0], [5, 8, 80.0]],
[[10, 12, 80.0]],
[[14, 16, 80.0], [13, 20, 81.0]],
[[14, 16, 80.0], [13, 20, 81.0]],
[[22, 24, 80.0]],
[[26, 28, 80.0], [25, 40, 80.0]],
[[26, 28, 80.0], [25, 40, 80.0]],
[[40, 42, 80.0], [40, 41, 80.0]],
[[40, 42, 80.0], [40, 41, 80.0]],
[[44, 45, 80.0]]]

output_wanted=
 [[[2, 5, 71.1], [1, 3, 70.0]],
 [[5, 10, 80.0], [6, 9, 80.0], [5, 8, 80.0]],
 [[10, 12, 80.0]],
 [[14, 16, 80.0], [13, 20, 81.0]],
 [[22, 24, 80.0]],
 [[26, 28, 80.0], [25, 40, 80.0]],
 [[40, 42, 80.0], [40, 41, 80.0]],
 [[44, 45, 80.0]]]
```

i need something like the set function which does the job fast. but i can not use the set function in this case. is there any way for doing it?

Comment: You actually have a list of lists of lists, and it isn't clear how you want to remove duplicates in terms of the structure (e.g. if `[5,8,80.0]` appears inside two different sublists, which one do you keep it in?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `list` is not hashable.
You need to convert the elements of your `list` in `tuples` (which are hashable) before applying `set()`.

```
>>> my_list = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> result = [list(el) for el in set(tuple(el) for el in my_list)]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

*Updated* with your new data:

```
>>> [list(list(y) for y in el) 
        for el in set([tuple(tuple(x) for x in el) for el in my_list])]

[[[26, 28, 80.0], [25, 40, 80.0]],
 [[10, 12, 80.0]],
 [[40, 42, 80.0], [40, 41, 80.0]],
 [[44, 45, 80.0]],
 [[5, 10, 80.0], [6, 9, 80.0], [5, 8, 80.0]],
 [[22, 24, 80.0]],
 [[14, 16, 80.0], [13, 20, 81.0]],
 [[2, 5, 71.1], [1, 3, 70.0]]]
```

Comment: thanks for your nice answer. how this code could be changed to work on  the real data as i pasted in the question text?